# organization chart in flex 3.0

Tags: apache-flex, hibernate, ejb-3.0, jaas

Currently we are using flex 3.0 in our project and also i am new to flex. we want to show the organization chart.So after googling a lot i found some examples for organizational chart from yFiles and IBM ilog. But they both support from flex 4.0. So any can help me or give any ideas for organizational chart using flex 3.0.

Comment: Flex charts are included in 3 sdk, you should have no problems with it http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/html/help.html?content=charts_types_01.html

Answer (score 1):

I have used KAP Lap's product in the past for exactly this. It worked great.

http://lab.kapit.fr/default/kalileo/

Comment: Sorry for late reply, I have seen the site earlier but i have not found any example source code to follow. So can u please help me to find out some source code so that i can learn some thing as i have said i am new to flex.